# Html image id in table

Tags: javascript, html, image

Excuse me if I make mistakes as I am very new to html.

I am trying to create a table full of images with onclick events that I can track so that at the end of the program each representation of a seat that is clicked will add the id to a list that will change the class.  I figure giving each image an id would allow me to identify which image has been selected.

I have filled the table like this

```
<td>
  <img id="A1" src="images/available.gif" style="border:none" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="sold(this)" />
</td>
```

However to test this I have put :

```
alert(""+ this.id);
```

In the onclick event `sold(this)` and it is coming back undefined.  Is it bad practice to do add an id for each image or am I making a very silly mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><img id="A1" src="images/available.gif" style="border:none" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="sold(this)" /></td>
```

And in your javascript

```
function over (img) {
    alert(img.id);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this has really helped and showed me that it is picking up the id.  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`this` isn't what you think it is.  When you call this function:

```
function over(arg) {
    // reference "this" on some code
}
```

then in the scope of that function `this` very likely refers to the current `window` object, and is in no way related to the HTML element whose event handler happened to invoke that function.

Now, the HTML element itself has a notion of `this`, and notice how you're passing it to the function:

```
onmouseover="over(this)"
```

That means that the argument being passed to the function is a reference to the HTML element whose handler invoked the function.  You can reference that function argument:

```
function over(arg) {
    // reference "arg" on some code instead of "this"  for example:
    alert('' + arg.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other image tags that needs to have a click event :

```
$(document).on("click","img", function(e){
//your code here
});
```

Suggesting jQuery since this will help you add this event to any image that will be added dynamically.